# Max limit on neo4j batch

Tags: neo4j

Is there a limit to the Neo4J rest handle of http://server/db/data/batch ?? I can post 294 x 6 elements (2x nodes 2x relationships 2x labels) in a batch its fine however the minute I start going to 295 `MATCH (n:Domain) RETURN count(n:Domain)` returns 0 (instead of the increase). Is there a limit of 1764 items per batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that my Ubuntu terminal had a buffer limit of 128kb and as such can only post queries of that specific size. The reason therefore had nothing to do with Cypher/Neo4j but rather CURL couldn't execute the query.